# Função não reconhece variável

Tags: python

```
p1pos = 0
def rodada(a):
    if a == 1:
        p1pos += sortear()
        print('Posição do P1: ', p1pos)
        acerto = pergunta()
        if p1pos in cAvanco and acerto == True:
            p1pos += 1
            print('Mais uma casa. P1: ', p1pos)
        elif p1pos in cRetro and acerto == True:
            p1pos = p1pos
            print('Casa de retrocesso. Mas você acertou. P1: ', p1pos)
        elif p1pos in cRetro and acerto == False:
            p1pos -= 1
            print('Você errou em uma casa de retrocesso. Posição P1: ', p1pos)
        else:
            print('Casa neutra, sua posição continua a mesma. P1: ', p1pos)
```

Erro: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'p1pos' referenced before assignment

Comment: A variável está definida fora do escopo da função, portanto ela serve apenas para leitura, você não pode alterar seu conteúdo e daí o erro. Você pode enviá-la como argumento da sua função, jogar toda a lógica para dentro de uma classe ou então (algo pouco recomendado) declará-la como global.

Comment: Se eu colocar a var como argumento, ao ser chamada a função, ela conseguirá editar o valor da variável que está fora da função?